# What is X-Google-Original-From used for?

Tags: email, gmail, spam-prevention, email-filter, alpine-mail

In connection with:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/763097/101935

I am looking to understand what the use and purpose of `X-Google-Original-From` actually is.

From what I see, I think I've managed to prevent Gmail from generating this portion of the header.

Looking just to better understand how Google, or even email clients or spam filters, might use this field. Or even its non-presence.

Comment: Did you Google `X-Google-Original-From`? The first result on Google explains this mystery.

Comment: I must not have seen that result @Gantendo

Answer (score 2):

You will find explanations in the bug-report
[X-Google-Original-From #1311](https://github.com/gophish/gophish/issues/1311):

> This is a feature of Gmail, likely there to help prevent spoofing. I'm
> afraid there isn't anything we can do in Gophish to prevent this.
>
> That's how Google's Gmail and G Suite SMTP servers flag your aliases.
> You need to authorize it in gmail as a send from address and complete
> verification before the SMTP server will leave your email with the
> correct "From" address and not flag it.
>
> It's not 100% transparent as DKIM is still performed with the default
> SMTP account email. Microsoft's outlook.com smtp servers provide more
> useful error messages, instead of just flagging silently like google
> does. It's likely a legacy issue.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, upon further research, have uncovered some interesting insights.

When examining email headers, the X- prefix typically indicates that the header is non-standard and specific to the service that added it. Google has added this header to provide additional information about the original sender's address.

> In the context of a reverse proxy setup using Nginx, IIS, or Apache,
> the X-Original-* headers, which include X-Google-Original-From,
> represent the original header value received in HttpContext.Connection
> and HttpContext.Request. When the HttpContext.Connection and
> HttpContext.Request are changed to the left-most value in the
> X-Forwarded-* header, the X-Original-* headers are used to save the
> original values[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57759419/x-original-for-header-whats-its-purpose).
>
> In the context of email routing and filtering, the
> X-Google-Original-From header can be used to filter emails based on
> the original sender’s address. For instance, if an email is forwarded
> through a Gmail account, the X-Google-Original-From header can contain
> the original sender’s email address. Email clients or servers can then
> use this information to route or filter the email accordingly[2](https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33452).

Regarding how Google, email clients, or spam filters might use this field, it would depend on their specific implementation and configuration. The absence of this field might not have a significant impact unless a system specifically relies on it for certain operations.